# positioning node with matrix inside

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish the nodes distribute horizontally side by side! and align nodes on top! but currently, it's overlapped.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
        nodes={draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1em,
            text height=1em,baseline=center},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2}]
    \node[mymat] (m0) {
        0 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=1cm of m0] (m1) {
        0 \\
        1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=1cm of m1.west,anchor=west] (m2) {
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=1cm of m2.west,anchor=west] (m3) {
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0  & 0\\
    1 & 1  & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 1  & 1\\
   1 & 0  & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `west` anchors. You can set (and change) the `node distance`. This is easier than saying every time `right=1cm of ...`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
        nodes={draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1em,
            text height=1em,baseline=center},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2},node distance=1cm]
    \node[mymat] (m0) {
        0 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m0] (m1) {
        0 \\
        1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m1] (m2) {
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m2] (m3) {
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0  & 0\\
    1 & 1  & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 1  & 1\\
   1 & 0  & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to align them at the top, use `north east` and `north west` anchors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
        nodes={draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1em,
            text height=1em,baseline=center},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2},node distance=0.5cm]
    \node[mymat] (m0) {
        0 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m0.north east,anchor=north west] (m1) {
        0 \\
        1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m1.north east,anchor=north west] (m2) {
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    };
    \node[mymat,right=of m2.north east,anchor=north west] (m3) {
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0  & 0\\
    1 & 1  & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 1  & 1\\
   1 & 0  & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, how to change it to align on top, I try to change anchor to north west but it doesn't work

Comment: @lucky1928 Now I think I understand why you put these anchors. You need to use `north east` and `north west` anchors, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, perfect. not sure why the text not in the center of node!

Comment: @lucky1928 To have the nodes horizontally centered, use `nodes={draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1em,
            text height=1em,baseline=center,align=center}`. To have them completely centered, use something like `nodes={draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries,minimum size=1.6em,anchor=center},`.